# Using constants in Lightning Components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, es6

What is the correct way of declaring and using constants in Lightning Components.

I am seeing different behaviours depending on organisations I am in.

Basic way of having pass-by-value and immutable variables in JS is:

`let state = [1,2,3]
const initState = Object.assign([], state)`

However, after assigning both to different aura attributes, I am seeing somehow initState getting modified too, which should be impossible in first place for two reasons - it's a constant AND it's been cloned.

Does Lightning framework does something to override this behaviour?

**Edit**: The most obvious solution could be using unbound expressions in `default` parameter on `aura:attribute`:

```
<aura:attribute type="Object[]" name="data"/>
<aura:attribute type="Object[]" name="initData" default="{#v.data}"/>
```

Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work. Possibly because it assigns initial state of undefined and stop further assignments.

Comment: I think we need to see more source code. I will tell you this: const doesn't protect an object's properties from being modified; it literally only protects the reference from being updated. You can use const in a function and it works as const should, but it doesn't do what I think you think it does. Including some simple code we can copy-paste in to a component that demonstrates your problem would be ideal.

Comment: @sfdcfox I realised one thing tomorrow - Object.assign() is a shallow clone - only surface properties are copied by value, deeper ones are copied by reference. It's a known issue with JS.

Answer (score 3):

We copy the attributes from the default values when we create new instances of the components. Otherwise, a change to one instance would effect changes in others.

If you do not want an attribute changed, make it a function call value.

```
<aura:attribute type="Integer" name="initData" default="{!1+1}"/>
```

This should prevent anyone from being able to change initData

```
cmp.set("v.initData", 5); // Ignored.
```